# JAVA: How to detect enter key as an invalid input for input validation

Tags: java

I want to make everything except numbers an invalid input. Currently I am using an InputMismatchException and catching it when I run the code. What do I need to do to detect if the user inputs nothing, but just presses the enter key?

```
boolean firstInput = false;
        while(firstInput == false)
        {
            System.out.println("1st complex number:");
            try 
            {
            numberA = getComplex();
            firstInput = true;
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Your input is invalid. Please try again.");
                firstInput = false;
            }
        }


public static Complex getComplex() throws InputMismatchException
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        double[] tempComplexNumbers = new double[2];

        for (int i = 0; i < tempComplexNumbers.length; i++)
        {
            if(i == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Please enter the real part of your complex number.");
            }
            else if(i == 1)
            {
                System.out.println("Please enter the imaginary part of your complex number.");
            }
            tempComplexNumbers[i] = keyboard.nextDouble();
        }

        return new Complex(tempComplexNumbers[0], tempComplexNumbers[1]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only time `Scanner` pays any attention to line boundaries (i.e., when ENTER is pressed) is when you are calling `nextLine()` (or `hasNextLine()`).  With `nextDouble()`, the `Scanner` treats blank lines as just more white space between numbers to be ignored.

If you want to know when the user pressed ENTER without entering any data, you'll have to give up the convenience of using `keyboard.nextDouble()` to read your numbers directly from the input, and instead process the input one line at a time using `keyboard.nextLine()` to read each and every line.  With a line in hand, you can then accordingly, depending on whether or not the user typed something on that line.  For example:

```
String line = keyboard.nextLine();
if (line.length() == 0) 
    System.out.println("You didn't enter anything");
else 
    System.out.println("You entered: " + line);
```

Of course, now that you're not using `keyboard.nextDouble()` to read the `double` numbers directly from the keyboard, it's up to you to parse the number on each non-blank line yourself.  It's not hard, just one more thing to know and do.  One way is to use `Double.parseDouble`:

```
double doubleValue = Double.parseDouble(line);
```

In the case of bad input, this will throw a `NumberFormatException` rather than an `InputMismatchException`, so be prepared for that little difference.

You could also use another new `Scanner` object to process the line in much the same way you were doing with the `keyboard` scanner:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(line);
double doubleValue = sc.nextDouble();
// OR all on one line:
double doubleValue = (new Scanner(line)).nextDouble();
```